# Contact form wont submit. Shows FILE NOT FOUND ERROR

Tags: javascript, php, html

I just recently built the company website for the placement which I am working at. I am in the process of learning web design/development. So far the website has been completed. Here is the link to the website: [www.f-sharpmedia.com](http://www.f-sharpmedia.com).

The problem is when I fill in the contact form in the contact page and press submit it seems to say there a file is not found. I am confused. I have a `contact.html` page which consists of HTML layout of the contact along with behaviour added to it using JavaScript.

Along this I have a PHP file called `sendmail.php` which consists of the basic validation you would have for a contact form along with the company email for inquiries to be sent. I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)_  In other words, once you fix your site, nobody is going to be able to see the original problem.  Please post the relevant code within your OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The form submits to contact.php and this file seems to be missing ( http://www.f-sharpmedia.com/contact.php )

Relevant code from your site:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
```

As you can see the action is set to contact.php. My guess is it should be linked to the sendmail.php file you're validating it with.

Comment: Thanks A lot man !!! Let me try this out :D

Answer (score 1):

You have written your code for the sending the mail in sendmail.php but in the action you have given the path of contact.php so try the below code

```
<form method="post" action="sendmail.php">
```